# How to close the table in log4j HTMLLayout

Tags: java, log4j

Whe I use log4j HTMLLayout it generetes html without closing `</table>` tag.
So next time logs are generating then html breaks as you understand.

```
log4j.appender.abc.layout = org.apache.log4j.HTMLLayout
```

Why it happens and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

It's a really old bug which could be found [here](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=7948). Maybe you should upgrade the version you use.